# If statement with or not working as expected

Tags: python, if-statement

My program first asks the user what is wrong with their mobile phone and when the user writes their answer, the program detects keywords and outputs a solution. I used "or" statements but when I input "*My phone dropped in water and my speakers don't work*" it should output "*you need new speakers. if waters been in contact you also may need a new motherboard if it doesn't come on*" but instead it outputs "*you will need your screen replacing*"

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong and tell me how I can overcome this problem in the future.

```
import time #This adds delays between questions
name = input ("what is your name?")
problem1 = input("hello there,what is wrong with your device?")
if "cracked" or "screen broke" in problem1:
    print("you will need your screen replacing")
elif "water" or "speakers" in problem:
    print("you need new speakers. if waters been in contact you also may need a new motherboard if it doesnt come on")
```

Comment: change problem to problem1 in you elif condition.

Comment: The cell phone repair industry is [really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584784/how-to-make-a-list-go-to-a-def) [taking off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525074/how-do-i-split-the-solutions-in-my-code) recently ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mis-understand `or`.  In programming, `or` is slightly different from in English.  `x or y in z` means `"is x True or is y in z?"`.  If the first argument (`x`) is non-empty, that means that it evaluates to `True`.  No check is made for anything's presence in `z`.  If `x` is empty, it evaluates to `False` and there is a check for `y`'s presence in `z`, but not `x`'s presence.  You need to create a new test for each one.  Also, you used `problem` instead of `problem1` in your second `elif`:

```
if "cracked" in problem1 or "screen broke" in problem1:
    ...
elif "water" in problem1 or...
    ...
```

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly sure what's happening is not that True and False aren't in problem1, it's that "cracked" is truthy, and the or is short circuiting

Comment: I just tested; you are right.  I'll edit my answer right away.  Thanks.