# Python - Using Files as a Database - Won't Always Print

Tags: python, file, loops

I'm a beginner at python. I want the user to input a problem and then the program should pick out words and read the file accordingly. For example, if they used the word 'water' then it will read the appropriate line and print it. At the moment it only works if that key word is at the end out the inputted string.

```
screen = ["display", "screen", "broken", "glass", "cracked"]                 
software = ["frozen", "stuck", "weird", "flashing" , "virus" , "reboot" ,"loop"]
body = ["broken" , "dented" , "dropped" , "smashed"]
water = ["wet" , "water" , "rain" , "damage" , "damaged" , "toilet" , "damp"]  
heat = ["overheating" , "hot" , "burning" , "burn" , "warm"]

problem = input("Please tell me what is wrong with your phone! ")  #this is to break up the users input so the words can be found seperately in the list
for j in problem.split():
pass

if j in screen:
solution = open("sfs.txt","r")
solutionread = solution.readline()
solution.close()
print(solutionread)
```

The rest of the code uses the if elif else code. It also uses readline to read the line I need. I am not very experienced and still learning so please try give me simple answers as too making it work effectively. Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Python requires proper indentation, are you sure you have that in your code? Also, what do you mean *Won't Always Print*? Be more specific.

Comment: Why do people keep asking about cell phone repair scripts? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525074/how-do-i-split-the-solutions-in-my-code) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584784/how-to-make-a-list-go-to-a-def) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605188/if-statement-with-or-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Do you need to search through lists names or through items in lists?

Comment: @Kevin probably a recent hw assignment

Comment: Since you want it to **print** the line **if** it has a certain word in it, don't you think you should iterate (hint: keyword) over the lines of the **file** and then **if** it has that word **print** it? Right now you're just reading one line and printing it unconditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not formatted with indents, so this may be wrong.

I suspect your indentation results in `if j in screen:` running after the `for j...` loop, not in it.  Also, read the definition of `pass`.